# mysql DISTINCT keyword not working for multiple column join table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have used mysql `DISTNCT` keyword for one of my mySQL query for avoid duplication of data displaying on search box.

But when I add multiple column names on `SELECT` it doesn't work.

Please advice how to proceed.

```
$query = "

    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT b.title,b.id, b.metakey
            FROM categories b
            WHERE  b.title like '%".$searchc."%' AND b.parent_id BETWEEN 84 AND 107 AND  b.level=3 ORDER BY LOCATE('".$searchc."', REPLACE(b.title, ' ', '')), b.title
    ) CLASS_CAT
        UNION ALL
            SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT a.title,  a.id, a.title as metakey
                    FROM content a join
                      categories b
                      on a.categories_id = b.id
                WHERE REPLACE(a.title, ' ', '') like '%".$searchc."%' 
                AND b.parent_id BETWEEN 84 AND 107 AND b.level=3 
             ) CLASS_ITEM
";
```

Comment: What should be DISTINCT in your sub-query?

Comment: @JayBlanchard : I want to add DISTINCT to a.title and b.title

Comment: Well `distinct` doesn't do a lot if you select an `id` column.  To filter out duplicates that appear both on the top and the bottom part of the union, replace `union all` with `union`.

Comment: @Andomar : done the changes , still issue remain. if i keep a.title and b.ttile on SELECt statemen its working , but when other coloumns alos mention on SELECt its not work. please advice

Comment: It would help if you explained "its not work".  Provide example input, actual output and desired output.  You can use sqlfiddle.com to set up an example.

Comment: Distinct is the #1 misused sql line.  I'd recommend using group by and understanding what combination of fields makes for a distinct row in your database (note : MySQL has a horrid bug in it...if your group by statement is incorrect, it'll run and return wrong results instead of an error)

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DISTINCT` will remove duplicates from the one `SELECT` statement. `UNION ALL` directs the system to not look for duplicates between the two sets you are combining (each `SELECT`).

Use `UNION` (without `ALL`) instead.  Note that removing the check for duplicates is faster, so if you know a set you're querying is unique, skip the dup check.

Also note that by row duplicates I'm referring to every column in every row.  If any column makes a row unique it will appear in the result set.  If you only want some columns to be unique you'll need to `GROUP BY` and aggregate the other columns (e.g. `GROUP_CONCAT`) or use additional queries to get other related data.

Comment: done the changes , still issue remain. if i keep a.title and b.ttile on SELECt statemen its working , but when other coloumns alos mention on SELECt its not work. please advice

Comment: DISTINCT and UNION ALL check for dups across the whole row returned. Every column must have the same value for a row to not duplicate. If you want title and id to be unique, what do you expect for the 3rd column if it doesn't duplicate?